# How to see own Accept Rate and what is algorithm that determines whether it will be shown

Tags: support

Is it possible to view your own Accept Rate i.e. as it is seen by others?

As a secondary question, is the algorithm that determines whether your Accept Rate will be shown documented somewhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. yes, just view one of your questions
2. see http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/08/new-question-asker-features/

Comment: I had trouble reaching the URL you provided but was able to locate a cached copy which explained why I could not see my own accept rate: "There must be at least four eligible questions as determined by the above rules, otherwise the statistic will not appear." when I have only asked three eligible questions.